# Convert string value to timestamp format

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have data like:

```
trx_date  trx_time
181125    114204
181125    230552
181125    172338
181125    083516
181125    090308
```

I want to convert from yymmdd and hhiiss to timestamp format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

I tried to use unix timestamp syntax :

```
select 
  trx_date,
  trx_time,
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(trx_date, trx_time), 'yyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
FROM table 
limit 100;
```

but it throws `error 1064`, what could go wrong?

Comment: What is that format, and why are date and time stored as separate entities?

Comment: @Strawberry its from our legacy core bank system, they stored data in files, not in database, so we have to parse the data if we want to insert the record to database

Comment: You said "convert int value". Are those really integers or strings? Do you have 5 digit values in date column?

Comment: @SalmanA oops sory, its string

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like unix timestamp but dates stored as `yymmdd` and `hhmmss`. Try converting like so:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('20', trx_date, trx_time), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
FROM (
    SELECT '181125' AS trx_date, '114204' AS trx_time UNION ALL
    SELECT '181125' AS trx_date, '230552' AS trx_time UNION ALL
    SELECT '181125' AS trx_date, '172338' AS trx_time UNION ALL
    SELECT '181125' AS trx_date, '083516' AS trx_time UNION ALL
    SELECT '181125' AS trx_date, '090308' AS trx_time
) AS x
-- 2018-11-25 11:42:04 etc
```

Be advised that the dates have two digit year which is ambiguous. The above example assumes all dates are 20xx.

Comment: will try, i have query above because i always work using apache hive, so i thought that the query is similiar

Comment: well, without '20' in concat, it won't work, the timestamp returns null, your previous answer were fine

Comment: The `%Y` (4 digit yer) also needs to be `%y` (2 digit year). If you are sure that all trx_dates belong to year 2000+ then prepend 20 and use `%Y`.